Probability of same value cards
Most of us are familiar with the card game “War”, where there is one 52 card deck, player A gets a card and player B gets a card. Whoever has the highest card wins. My question is regarding the likelihood of the round resulting in a tie, where both players draw the same number (player A gets a 7, player B gets a 7, etc). Further, l would like to add that all face cards (jack queen king) and 10 have the value of 0.
The cards are as follows
Ace-9 (ace is one, 2-9 have the value of their card)
10, jack , queen , king all equal 0
So, given that 4 out of the 13 cards are the same, and accounting for the possibility of back to back 3’s, 4’s etc, how can you determine statistically how often a tie would happen? I quickly shuffled some cards and played ~10 rounds of War with myself out of curiosity. I noticed that every 52 deck would have a minimum of 2 ties, with some shuffles resulting in over 5 ties. 52 cards = 26 hands. Is there some type of formula to this and is it scalable for 2 decks, 3 decks, 4 decks, etc? I assume the more decks you add, the theoretic probability will remain the same but the frequency would be more sporadic. But l am very uninformed!
Thank you for any and all answers.

For a $52$ card deck, are you asking for the expected number of ties? Also, could you justify your claim that there must be a minimum of two ties?

Yes, expected number of ties given that 4/13 cards have the same value and the possibility of say two 7’s getting turned. I added in the minimum of two ties after playing some rounds by myself out of curiosity, and personal experience l noted that every round had at least 2 ties. So that is 2/26 rounds that tied, some shuffles had over 5 ties, so l was looking for some mathematical average

The probability that a given round ends in a tie is not difficult to calculate:
If $A$ draws a card from Ace to 9 (which has probability $\frac{36}{52}$), the probability that $B$ draws the same rank is $\frac{3}{51}$.
If $A$ draws $10$, J, Q, or K (which has probability $\frac{16}{52}$), the probability that $B$ also draws $10$, J, Q, or K is $\frac{15}{51}$.
So the combined probability is
$$\frac{36}{52}\cdot\frac{3}{51}+\frac{16}{52}\cdot\frac{15}{51}=\frac{29}{221}\approx 0.1312$$
The expected number of ties when the full deck is dealt will be very close to
$$26\cdot\frac{29}{221}\approx 3.412$$
This might not be exact, because of cross-correlations (for instance, it is impossible to have exactly $25$ ties). But it is close enough for all practical purposes.
By the way, you can't draw any conclusions from just ten rounds. I ran a million rounds, and there were $81,376$ rounds with only one match, and $13,736$ rounds with no matches at all. And at the other end of the scale, three rounds finished with $13$ ties.

Awesome! Thank you so much for this reply. If you were too add more decks, how could you account for the additional cards? I imagine in theory everything stays the same, because theoretically everything would scale up and then reduce back down to the same as single deck 52 card. But do the additional cards add some type of variable worth accounting for? Thank you!

@Imhungbaby: Everyting just scales up, as near as makes no difference.

Thank you very much good sir!
